# Unknown Inbound UTP Packets

Tags: macos, wireshark, network-protocols, sniffing

I need some help figuring out something. I was looking at my network traffic using Wireshark and I saw a bunch of inbound UTP (uTorrent Transport Protocol) packets to my IP. About 10 different IP's every minute or so.

Whats the story with that? 
Should I block them? (I'm using a Mac)

It's really strange and stood out to me because I never used the BitTorrent protocol on this computer and we rarely used the protocol on this network in the last year, maybe once or twice at most.

Comment: I'd like to see that. Can you post a trace at CloudShark.org and link to it here?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, it just started the last few days and i'm getting bombarded with uTorrent packets. Did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I discovered the trafic was due to a program called Miro using DHT for the BitTorrent protocol.